# f-string like behaviour with explicit format method

Tags: python, f-string

With f-string  I can do like this:

```py
a = 10
f'a equals {a}'  # 'a equals 10'
f'b equals {a - 1}'  # 'b equals 9'
```

but when using `.format` I cannot do any operation on the variable:

```py
'b equals {a - 1}'.format(dict(a=10))  # KeyError: 'a  - 1'
```

The error message is clear - the format function treats everything in the `{}` as an argument name. Can I circumvent that somehow?

I cannot use the f-string, because the message is prepared before values of the variables are known.

EDIT:
Ok, it seems that it can not be possible - it would work as an implicit eval which would be very unsafe.

Comment: `'b equals {a}'.format(a=10 - 1)`…?

Comment: `'b equals {a - 1}'.format(**{'a - 1': a-1})` works if you really have to...

Answer (score 1):

When using format, the {} are a place holder for an expression. Do the arithmetic in the format argument, not in the place holder.

```
str = "a = {}"
a = 10
stra = str.format(a-1)
print(stra)
>> a = 9
```